# Actualizar listview SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-asynctask

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tomando como inicio estoy terminando mi app en android, y requiero actualizar mi listview personalizado cuando deslizo hacia abajo la pantalla.

Estoy implementando SwipeRefreshLayout solo que me quede atorado en la parte del metodo onRefresh y no se como actualizar mi listado, aclaro yo mi listview lo lleno desde un webservices utilizando la clase Asyntask.

Les dejo el codigo mi Layout y mi activity

layout..

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/clientes"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class Clientes extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> cliArrayList = new ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>();
    ArrayList<String> searchlist;
    MyArrayAdapter adaptador;
    public static String O_Cliente = "O_Cliente";
    DetalleMenu O_DetalleMenu;
    TextView textView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_clientes);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        O_DetalleMenu = (DetalleMenu) intent.getSerializableExtra("O_DetalleMenu");
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clientes);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView idcli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clienid);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Clientes.this, Detalle_Cliente.class);
                intent.putExtra("O_Cliente", (CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clienid)).getTag());
                intent.putExtra("O_DetalleMenu", (DetalleMenu) O_DetalleMenu);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        AsynClien task = new AsynClien();
        //Call execute
        task.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cliente, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        //permite modificar el hint que el EditText muestra por defecto
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                    adaptador.filter("");
                    list.clearTextFilter();
                } else {
                    adaptador.filter(newText);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }

    private class AsynClien extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList> {


        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
            cliArrayList = webService.Clientes(O_DetalleMenu.getDocumento());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        //Make Progress Bar visible
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Clientes.this);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Cargando Clientes...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

        }

        //Once WebService returns response
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
            super.onPostExecute(arrayList);
            if (cliArrayList.size() != 0) {
                dialog.dismiss();

                adaptador = new MyArrayAdapter(Clientes.this, cliArrayList);///* no se usa your_array_list
                //list.setAdapter(adaptador);

                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clientes);
                listView.setAdapter(adaptador);


            } else {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }




    public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>{

        private List<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> searchList;

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> ArrayClientes)
        {
            super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
            this.searchList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.searchList.addAll(cliArrayList);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return cliArrayList.size();
        }



        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;

            CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor O_Cliente = getItem(position);

            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_cliente, parent, false);
            }


            //Obteniendo instancias de los text views
            TextView nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombrecli);
            TextView saldov = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtsaldov);
            TextView saldot = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtsaldot);
            TextView idcli = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clienid);


            //INICIALIZAR FORMAT
            DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

            nombre.setText(O_Cliente.getClienteDescripcion());
            nombre.setTag(O_Cliente);

            saldov.setText(numberFormat.format(O_Cliente.getSaldoVencido()));
            saldot.setText(numberFormat.format(O_Cliente.getSaldo()));

            idcli.setText(String.valueOf(O_Cliente.getCliente()));
            idcli.setTag(O_Cliente);

            // Se almacena en settag el objeto Cliente
            convertView.setTag(O_Cliente);

            //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
            return convertView;
        }

        public void filter(String newText) {
            newText = newText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            cliArrayList.clear();
            if (newText.length() == 0) {
                cliArrayList.addAll(searchList);
            } else {
                for (CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor s : searchList) {
                    if (s.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(newText)) {
                        cliArrayList.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


}
```

Codigo refresh

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setDistanceToTriggerSync(20);// in dips
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setSize(SwipeRefreshLayout.DEFAULT);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new AsynClien().execute();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al realizar un "pull to refresh", debes ejecutar tu Asynctask

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                 new AsynClien().execute();
                 //adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
```

y dentro del método `onPostExecute()` de tu Asynctask, actualizar el adapter con los nuevos datos, `adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();` que es lo que al parecer ya tienes realizado.

Para que el "indicador", que en realidad es un progressBar circular aparezca o desaparezca se usa el método **[setRefreshing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setRefreshing(boolean))**

> Notifica al widget que el estado de actualización ha cambiado. No
>   llamar cuando la actualización se esta realizando.

Para forzar a que aparezca al inicio:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

Para forzar a que desaparezca al final:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

Comment: ok deja hago eso y te aviso, gracias

Comment: ya realize los cambios ya me funciona, pero cuando el push refres hacia abajo.. me actualiza los datos, pero el el icono que aparece de actualizar no se quita.... dejo la imagen

Comment: ya lo pude arreglar... les dejo el código de como lo dejo. solo le agregue unas lineas de código a mi refresh

Comment: se realiza con el método setRefreshing, en otras ocasiones no se si sea por el OS pero al inicio no se muestra. En cuanto a  adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged(); también lo podrías agregar en el onPostExecute(), saludos!

Comment: gracias, por tu ayuda, abri otro foro donde tengo un problema con un searchview que puse en el actionbar, para ver si me ayudas...

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Por nada, si te sirvió mi respuesta recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Ahora veo tu otra pregunta, saludos!.

Comment: ya la marque, gracias

Comment: Si pudiste checar mi otra pregunta?

Comment: hold on estoy en un meeting :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40017/discussion-between-hugo-rodriguez-and-elenasys).