# Función actualizar activity (Asynctask GET)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listview

Tengo una actividad donde se ejecuta un `Asynctask` que obtiene datos de una BD y los muestra en un `LISTVIEW`. EL problema puntual es que tengo en el `toolbar` un icono(`Button`) de actualizar he intentado algo y no me ha funcionado. Deseo implementar un `SwipeRefreshLayout` y esta misma función copiarla en el icono del `toolbar`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mostrar_pregunta, menu);
    return true;
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.atras) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.Actualizar){// Aqui es donde deseo colocar el codigo para actualizar he intentado ejecutar AsyncRetrieve que es donde se obtiene los datos y la app se cierra.
        //new AsyncRetrieve().execute();
        return true;

    } else if(id == R.id.salir){
        finishAffinity();
        return  true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: cuando se cierra la app, que error recibes?

Comment: Hola nuevamente @sioesi Jaja la verdad no muestra un error, simplemente se cierra como si fuera una funcion para cerrar la app

Comment: que extraño que no recibas un error, yo tengo exactamente lo mismo en una app y me funciona correctamente, estas seguro que no entra en `else if(id == R.id.salir){`

Comment: He corrido nuevamente la app y ahora ha funcionado. seguramente las veces anteriores entraba en salir. creo que deberia borrar esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

En el caso del **SwipeRefreshLayout** lo he conseguido a continuación el codigo
Declaro la variable
En el XML debemos envolver el listview

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
```

Ahora pasamos a la clase JAVA, enlazamos de la clase con el XML

```
swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
```

Ahora ejecuto el Asynctask que obtiene los datos los muestra en el listview

```
swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new AsyncRetrieve().execute();
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    });
    // Configure the refreshing colors
    swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es similar a esta **[pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10372/actualizar-listview-swiperefreshlayout)**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/clientes"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Agregar un listener a tu `SwipeRefreshLayout` y mandas llamar tu `AsyncTask` de esta forma:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                 new AsyncRetrieve().execute(); 
                 //Indicador!
                 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);                 
            }
        });
```

---

Para que el ProgressBar circular que indica se esta refrescando, si lo deseas habilitar/deshabilitar se usa el método **[setRefreshing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setRefreshing(boolean))**

> [setRefreshing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setRefreshing(boolean)) Notifica al widget que el estado de actualización ha cambiado. No
>   llamar cuando la actualización se esta realizando.